How to get value before calling .forRoot?
export function getApiKey(config: WebConfigService): Promise<boolean> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    config.getConfigLoaded().subscribe(key => {
      if (key) {
         apikey = config.getString('properties', 'apikey');
        
        resolve(true);
      } else {
        reject(new Error('API Key not found'));
      }
    });
  });

I want to get the key resolved and then call the forroot so that
This code needs some work as the forroot comes undefined
should have correct key`
I see, it seems like there might be a misunderstanding. In Angular, it's not a recommended practice to directly access instance members from static methods because static methods are associated with the class itself, not with instances of the class. However, you can still achieve your goal by following a different approach.
 imports: [
    // FwBuilderModule.forRoot(apikey), this imports should be passed correct key

static forRoot(apiKey: string):ModuleWithProviders<FwBuilderModule>{
    @NgModule({
        imports: [
          CommonModule,
          CerillionBuilderBridgeComponent,
          BuilderModule.forRoot(apiKey)


usually libraries provide a way to provide an apiKeyFactory instead of apiKey. this way you would beable to provide a key. what library do you have problems with?

builder.io - using angular it provides mE api  key which i need to be sure to put in forroot(key) so that i will be navigated and shown correct site at builder.io workspace

I would propose you to save value in some config service via the app initializer and then build api key with a factory, that depends on the config service
// config.service
export class ConfigService {
  apiKey: string;
  
  async load() {
    const key = // get a key in an async way
    this.apiKey = key;
  }
}

// module
imports: [BuilderModule],
providers: [{
  provide: BUILDER_API_KEY,
  useFactory: () => inject(ConfigService).apiKey,
}]
// app initializer
providers: [{
   provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
   useFactory: () => {const service = inject(ConfigService); return () => service.load()},
   multi: true
  }]

